# Mongod: inserting entry with customer _id (monk/node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I have read that any `_id` type can be used except for Array. (But cannot seem to find. Can you guys confirm this please?)

I would like the username (string) to be the `_id` for performance reasons.

In Node.js:

```
const monk = require('monk');
const db = monk('localhost:27017/test',
    function(err) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err.toString());
    });
//const doc = {user: 'aa', password: 'password'};
//const doc = {_id: 'aa', password: 'password'};
const doc = {_id: monk.id('aa'), password: 'password'};
var users = db.get('users');
users.insert([doc]);
```

The first commented line works, but the other lines both error out:

- `_id: monk.id('aa')` errors out immediately
- `_id: 'aa'` errors out when doing `users.insert()` because I guess it tries to cast the string into an Id

The error is the same regardless:

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

How can I use a given string for `_id`?

ps: to run this code, you need mongo running, `mongod --dbpath data`, and nodejs: `npm install monk; nodejs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`monk.id(ARG)` will cast `ARG` to an `ObjectId` ([documentation](https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/id.html)), which is not what you want.

Instead, just pass the string directly:

```
const doc = { _id: 'aa', password: 'password' };
```

Since Monk also casts id's to `ObjectId` automatically, you have to disable autocasting:

```
const db   = monk('localhost:27017/test', ...);
db.options = { 
  safe    : true,
  castIds : false
};
```

Comment: The problem is that then I get the same error when doing the insertion. See the updated post.

Comment: Thank you, I have chosen your answer. Side question though: Do you think there is any advantage to saving my usernames as `_id`? I am doing this because I figured it would be faster when doing find. But I want to keep my server KISS. Do you think I should just use `username: 'aa'` and let him choose the `_id`?

Comment: I don't think using a username as `_id` will be faster than using an `ObjectId`. I would use `ObjectId` myself (it has the added advantage that it contains a timestamp, they allow for easier sorting, and it's easier if you evern want to allow a user to change their username and you have other documents referencing the user document, which works much better if `_id` is an independent value).

Comment: But should I set `username` as a primary key then for faster finding? Sorry to be a bother. This is trivial stuff, but I cannot seem to find nothing very useful about primary keys on mongo.

Comment: You can add a unique index for the `username` field, so finding users will be fast. That's generally how "things are done" in MongoDB :)